# Java: implementing simple list without lib

Tags: java, list

How can I implement a simple OOP list in java, without using any Java lib?

What are the typical features of Java lists?

What do you think about if someone tells you "list" regarding java? I don't know if it is a linked or whatever list.

Comment: I will ask linked list or array (which is list in python).

Comment: That's an odd requirement.  Is this for a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the javadocs for `java.util.List` and see what methods it defines to get an indea. Then, you can think about an implementation of yours.

The above interface has a lot of implementations: `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` being just some of the most popular.

Answer (score 1):

without using any Java lib?

you can create an object

```
class myList{
  myList nextitem;
  Info moreInfo
}

myList l = new myList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical features of a Java list are defined in the standard [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface.  If you implement this interface in such a way that the code

```
List<Foo> bar = new ArrayList<Foo>();
// Other code that calls methods from the List interface, using bar
```

and

```
List<Foo> bar = new YourCustomList<Foo>();
// The same other code
```

behave the same (and of course the other code exercises the list features you care about), then I'd consider you to have implemented a Java list.

I'd note that you don't have to implement *all* the methods in java.util.List (the ones you don't implement can throw `UnsupportedOperationException`), but you should favor implementing all of them unless your list is different from the "standard" list interface that ArrayList presents.  For instance, a read-only list should throw `UnsupportedOperationException` on an attempt to add or remove an element.

Answer (score 0):

Primary feature is to go give possibility of adding not bounded - by creation parameter - number  of the elements, so if don't have any other requirements (access time, etc.) just enhance  [] with dynamic re-sizing during add and remove operation.

But..  List is part of the collections so if you want to meet this "requirement" you should implement required functionality.